# Custom Keyboard - Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard, soft-keyboard

I am following a tutorial on creating a custom keyboard for an Android device. I am using Android Studio 2.1.2. There is no activity in the program because you have to activate the keyboard in the language & input settings.

When I run the program I get this error: "Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity"

I have posted on the site but have gotten no response. I followed the tutorial step by step and looked it over for a couple of days. I am new to Android Studio and Android applications and was wondering if anyone knew how to help me.

This is the link to the site I am following: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

Answer (score 12):

I just figured out what needed to be done. 
You have to edit the configurations and change the launch option to "nothing". This way it won't try to launch and activity that does not exist. 
run->edit configurations then look for the launch options

Answer (score 0):

Well you have answered it by yourself.

If you are creating an keyboard application(inputmethod) in android, everytime you compile and run your applcation, it will show a warning that there is no default activity since it's InputMethodService, the service. Even you add activity like some settings activity for your keyboard, it will still show you warnings and it's the normal operation.